# Pass array to button's href

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how I can download sole document with button:

```
<Button aria-label="download" href={props.myLink} download target="_blank" size="small">
    <CloudDownloadIcon />
</Button>
```

What if props.myLink will be an array of strings?
Then how to pass each elements of array to href?

Comment: props.myLink shouldn't be an array, but if it can't be avoided then it is better to just loop over the array and generate a button for each link

Comment: Do you want to render multiple buttons or a single one? What's the format of `props.myLink`?

Comment: `props.myLink` in first example is a string and in target example is string[]. I want to download multiple files by one button click

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `onClick` property instead of `href` to call a custom function? Then you can call `window.open` for each item in your `props.myLink`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DownloadButton extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.downloadFiles = props.myLink;
  }

  downloadFiles() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.downloadFiles.length; i++) {
      window.open(this.downloadFiles[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <Button aria-label="download" onClick={downloadFiles}>
        <CloudDownloadIcon />
    </Button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Of course, if you want to generate a button for each item in `props.myLink`, you can do so like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DownloadButton extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.downloadFiles = props.myLink;
  }
  
  const buttons = this.downloadFiles.map((file) =>
    <Button aria-label="download" href={file} download target ="_blank" size="small">
        <CloudDownloadIcon />
    </Button><br/>
  );
  
  return (
    <div>{buttons}</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

All these is under the assumption that `props.myLink` is an array of strings.